# Reading FBO depth attachment whilst depth testing

Tags: opengl, opengl-3, fbo, depth-buffer

I'm working with a deferred rendering engine using OpenGL 3.3. I have an FBO set up as my G-buffer with a texture attached as the depth component.

In my lighting pass I need to depth test (with writes disabled) to cull unnecessary pixels. However, I'm currently writing code which will reconstruct world position coordinates, this will also need access to the depth buffer.

Is it legal in Opengl 3.3 to bind a depth attachment to a texture unit and sample it whilst also using it for depth testing in the same pass?

I can't find anything specifically about it in the docs but my gut tells me that using the same buffer/texture for two different purposes will produce undefined behaviour. Does anybody know for sure? I have a limited set of hardware to test on and don't want to make false assumptions about what works.

Comment: Comments in [this thread](https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/173408-Depth-texture-bound-to-FBO-and-texture-unit) suggests it is undefined behaviour.
Leaving the question open since I can't find anything definitive.

Comment: Fibbles is right. As far as I know you cant read and write to a FBO in the same pass. And since sampling is reading the FBO and rendering into the depth buffer is writing this might not work.

Comment: After checking the spec, I agree with Alfonse Reinheart in the thread you linked. Common sense suggests that this might be ok if you disable depth writes. But I couldn't find anything in the spec that specifically allows this. The way I read it, this still meets the conditions of a render feedback loop, even with depth writes disabled, and behavior is therefore undefined.

Comment: I eventually tested this on various hardware/drivers and the results were definitely undefined. I eventually had to implement the G-Buffer with a depth attachment and an GL_R32F colour attachment which also contained depth the depth info so that I could read it later in the lighting pass. It seems wasteful at first glance but it is still more efficient than the depth attachment plus GL_RGB32F colour attachment (for world coords) that I was using previously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the very least this creates a situation where memory coherency cannot be guaranteed (coherency is something you sort of assume at all stages in the traditional pipeline pre-GL4 and have no standardized control over either).

The driver just might cache this memory in an undesirable way since this behavior is undefined. You would like to think that an appropriate combination of writemask and sampling would be a strong hint not to do that, but that is all up to whoever designed the driver and your results will tend to vary by hardware vendor, platform and hardware generation.

This scenario is a use-case for things like NV's texture barrier extension, but that is vendor specific and still does not tackle the problem entirely. If you want to do this sort of thing portably, your best bet is to promote the engine to GL4 and use standardized features for early fragment tests, barriers, etc.

---

Does your composite pass really need a depth buffer in the first place though? It sounds like you want to re-construct per-pixel position during lighting from the stored depth buffer. That's entirely possible in a framebuffer with no depth attachment at all.

Your G-Buffers will already be filled at this point, and after that you no longer need to do any fragment tests. The one fragment that passed all previous tests is what's eventually written to the G-Buffer and there's no reason to apply any additional tests to it when it comes time to do lighting.

Comment: I have accepted your answer, though some references would have been appreciated.

Comment: Fragment tests are required during the lighting pass. Point lights for example use spherical bounding volumes. All fragments that are inside the volume have lighting calcs run on them. Without a depth test a spherical bounding volume is actually a cylinder extending from the camera to the far clip plane.  If the point light is far away it doesn't matter because the cylinder diameter is small. If it is close we encounter the worst case scenario; the cylinder is so wide it covers the entire screen. By performing a GEQUAL depth test, fragments behind the volume never receive lighting calcs.

Comment: Oh, I see. I use a different methodology altogether, I have a pre-pass before lighting that breaks everything into tiles. For each tile, I have a list of lights that cover it (this is where depth/stencil testing happens). By the time lights are composited, the need for per-fragment tests of any sort is eliminated. There's a little bit of extra workload by evaluating the lighting shader for pixels inside the tiles that aren't completely covered, but it works itself out in the end since these tiles can be evaluated from a compute shader instead of fragment. That's GL4 era stuff though.

Comment: In GL3, I think most places would have you start off using the stencil buffer for coverage testing rather than the depth buffer. The most obvious benefit comes from point lights -- a pixel can be in one of three possible states (too close), (inside) or (too far). A single depth test (which gives a binary result) couldn't properly deal with that and you'd be dealing with false positives. Since you can't (in GL3 anyway) sample the stencil buffer from a shader, if your coverage tests during lighting use it instead of the depth buffer, you also avoid the coherency issues discussed in my answer.

Comment: I've never seen any tangible performance benefits to being that accurate though. Tiling everything works just as well, and that has the simplest coverage criteria you could imagine.

Comment: I did try out using stencil testing but I found that because of the extra pass it required there wasn't any real performance gain, just an increase in code complexity. Rendering with front face culling (to stop the light volumes from disappearing when the camera is inside) and a GEQUAL depth test eliminates most of the fragments that don't require lighting calcs. There are still some false positives; fragments in front of the volume will receive unnecessary lighting calcs but because of the way perspective works (volumes in the distance appear smaller) this is kept to a minimum.

Comment: I have just started reading up on tile based deferred rendering, it is an interesting topic. Thanks for pointing me towards it.